# Unity2D: How do I move the player to the touch position

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I can't figure it out, how do I move the Player slowly, scaleable with a speed value to the point, where the touch happens?

My Camera is attached to the player.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Vector2.Lerp, Input.GetTouch, and Touch.Position. Here is a code example that prints the current touch position:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
{
    Debug.Log(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
}
```

Now, we should add this to a certain position in the world. We can use Camera.ScreenPointToRay for this part:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
    RaycastHit2D hit;
    Physics2D.Raycast(ray, out hit);
    Debug.Log(hit.point);
}
```

Here, we actually get the position in the world that you have pressed. We can then use this along with Lerp to move an object to the position:

```
public float scaleFactor = 0.2f; //how fast to move object.
public GameObject moving // drag the object you want to move in this slot.
public Vector2 Lerped;//Vector3 if you’re working in 3D.
public float time = 0f;
public bool lerping = false;
private Vector2 newPos = new Vector2();
//Vector3 if you’re working in 3D.

RaycastHit2D hit;//remove the 2D after RaycastHit if you are in 3D. If you are in 2D, leave it.
float dist;
...
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
    Physics2D.Raycast(ray, out hit);//same with this one. Remove the 2D if you are in 3D.
    Debug.Log(hit.point);
    dist = Vector2.Distance(moving.transform.position, hit.point);
    //Vector3 if you’re in 3D.
    lerping = true;
}
if (lerping)
{
    time += Time.deltaTime * dist * scaleFactor;
    lerp(hit.point.x, hit.point.y, hit.point.z);
    //remove hit.point.z if you are in 2D.
}
else
{
    time = 0f;
}
if (moving.transform.position == new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y, hit.point.z);
//remove hit.point.z if in 2D, and switch Vector3 to Vector2 if in 2D.
{
    lerping = false;
}
moving.transform.position = newPos;
```

And then in another part of the script:

```
public void lerp(float x, float y, float z)
//remove the float z and the comma before it if you are in unity 2d.
{
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    //Vector2 and no z if you’re in 2D.

    newPos = Vector2.Lerp(moveObj, pos, time);
    //Vector3 if in 3D.
}
```

This is a pretty large script, and it’s pretty hard to explain, so I will say this: do what the comments tell you, and tell me if you get any errors. I haven’t actually tested the script, so if anyone notices them, please tell me.

Now, what the script does: basically, it gets the point of where you touched, and makes the player slowly go towards it (the speed changes by the distance and scaleFactor variable of which you can change.)

Comment: I did my best to do what I thought you meant.